# Cannot publish Visual Studio extension VsixPub0029 error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've started receiving this error recently when trying to publish my Visual Studio 2019 extension.
Best I can tell the manifest file isn't corrupted [this has been uploading for years now], this fails both with the VsixPublisher.exe and when I manually try to upload the VSIX to the MSFT marketplace. There is a schema warning on the internalName ('codestream-vs') but we've had that for years. Here is the error:

`VSSDK: error VsixPub0029 : An error occurred while communicating with the marketplace: UploadFile: The package contains an invalid VSIX manifest file. This VSIX does not apply to any product installed on this machine. The problem could be that the VSIX manifest's format is not recognized, or that the manifest has been corrupted.`

https://github.com/TeamCodeStream/codestream/blob/master/vs/publishManifest.json
https://github.com/TeamCodeStream/codestream/blob/master/vs/src/CodeStream.VisualStudio/source.extension.vsixmanifest

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same problem. Hardly changed anything in the extension but it won't publish, only a one line bug fix.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in the mean time. I was having the same issue, just retried and it went through as usual.

Comment: Yup, thanks for the headsup @JoséSimões, just tried again and it went through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VS Marketplace team has resolved the issue. Please try again.